# How do you fetch a Jenkins job's artifacts from a remote system?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifacts

I'd like to download an artifact file from Jenkins CI (e.g. file from the latest successful job) from a remote system. How can I do it? Do I need a plugin to do this?

Comment: Please demonstrate the research you have already done.

Comment: Seems like you should be using an external artifact repository depending on the type of artifacts you're producing.  Like a Maven repo for Java or a YUM repo for RedHat RPM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public URLs of artifacts can be found in Workspace of the job. It is advised to use ***view*** version of URL, so it is more consistent.

For archived files, [Archived Artifact Url Viewer](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Archived+Artifact+Url+Viewer+PlugIn) can provide URL to a file inside a zip or jar archive within the artifact folder of a build